# Произношение слов

Tags: орфоэпия

Есть ли стилистические различия в вариантных формах?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Только мне кажется, что слова из левого столбца, помеченного как "только /шн/", допустимо произносить через /чн/?

Answer (score 1):

Нет, это не стилистические варианты, а хронологические. Если не считать, что на сцене используется старомосковское -шн-, чтобы передать произношение старого времени.